# Редактор кривых безье three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

Есть ли пример подобного редактирования кривой(именно с доп. точками).на three js

[image: Пример]

Answer (score 0):

Да .нужно было больше вам внимательности
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_geometry_spline_editor.html
https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_geometry_spline_editor

Да это не совсем то что нужно но чучь ли не половина от задачи

Вам тут несколько three js нужен сколько понимание основ кривых.это не так уж и сложно .если не планируется что-то очень сложное вполне можно написать с 0 имея в руках только прямую

Хотя в three js есть уже что-то готовое с кривыми мб там реализация по удобнее будет

Но то что вы просите это простая квадратичная кривая
[https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%8C%D0%B5#:~:text=%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%8B%CC%81%D0%B5%20%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%8C%D0%B5%CC%81%20%E2%80%94%20%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%8B%20%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%85%2C%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5,%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C%20%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2%20%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%8C%D0%B5#:%7E:text=%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%8B%CC%81%D0%B5%20%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%8C%D0%B5%CC%81%20%E2%80%94%20%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%8B%20%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%85%2C%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5,%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C%20%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2%20%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9).

В вашем примере это грубо говоря 2 таких кривых
где у них 1 общая точка
У 1 конец а у 2 начало
А манипулятор представляет собой просто алгоритм изменяющий входящие параметры в этих 2 кривых и визуализация этих всех параметров в виде точек

https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/extras/curves/CubicBezierCurve3
Вот кривая